# limit javascript toggle according to select box value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is link of my current fiddle

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/demo_Ashif/4QkM8/)

JS --

```
$('.click').on({
    'click': function () {

        var origsrc = $(this).attr('src');
        var src = '';
        if (origsrc == 'http://imageshack.us/a/img703/8236/l6hu.png') src = 'http://imageshack.us/a/img20/1651/fibz.png';
        if (origsrc == 'http://imageshack.us/a/img20/1651/fibz.png') src = 'http://imageshack.us/a/img703/8236/l6hu.png';

        $(this).attr('src', src);

    }
});
```

i am able to toggle image onclick with another image and vice versa. This is okay, but i want to limit the toggle only when green image is already selected. If i select 3 from select box then i can toggle white image into green image only 3 times, not more than 3. I also need help for another scenerio - if i select 3 from select box and toggle first 3 image and next moment i change the 2nd image into white and click 5th image to turn green then it will be possible. I am week in javascript or jquery, so need proper information about this problem. So plz help me out.

Comment: Thanks for editing. I'm not getting reply, it's kiling me. :(

Comment: You should consider switching `classes` instead of `src attributes`, that will enable you to more easily calculate the current total number of selected boxes and compare it to the input value

Comment: If you can plz edit my fiddle, i am noob in javascript arena.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/4QkM8/8/ there you go, cleared a lot of stuff

Comment: @php_nub_qq: You should post that as an answer, not a comment.

Comment: @ColinDeClue this is a highly localized issue, I hardly believe this would be of use to anybody else

Comment: @php_nub_qq: Then you should vote to close the question as localized. The other answers are worse than yours, anyway.

Comment: @ColinDeClue post it as yours then, I give you full copyright privileges `:D`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update the function like this - fiddle is here - http://jsfiddle.net/4QkM8/5/

I changed id of select box to **selQty**

```
var selectedCount = 0;  
$('.click').on({
    'click': function () {               
            var origsrc = $(this).attr('src');
            var src = '';
        if (origsrc == 'http://imageshack.us/a/img703/8236/l6hu.png'){ if (selectedCount < $('#selQty').val()){src = 'http://imageshack.us/a/img20/1651/fibz.png';
 selectedCount ++;  
                                                                                                              }                                                                                                              }
        if (origsrc == 'http://imageshack.us/a/img20/1651/fibz.png') {src = 'http://imageshack.us/a/img703/8236/l6hu.png';selectedCount --;}

        $(this).attr('src', src == '' ? origsrc : src);  
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a more comprehensive approach [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Mjrn2/) which will keep your limit in sync and handle discrepancies when the limit changes.

```
var quantity = 0; // will maintain limit    
var stack = []; // will maintain ordered green buttons
$("#select").change(runWrapper);
function runWrapper() {
  quantity = Number($("#select").val()); // set the limit
  groom();  // turn off those that were turned on last
  //run();  // this is your run function, uncomment 
}
function groom(){
    // let's test if we are over the limit
    while(stack.length > quantity) {
        // remove last which was set to green
        $(stack.pop()).trigger("click")

        // to remove the oldest/first set to green use
        //  $(stack.shift()).trigger("click")
    }
}
$('.click').on({
    'click': function () {

            var origsrc = $(this).attr('src');
            var src = '';
        if (origsrc == 'http://imageshack.us/a/img703/8236/l6hu.png') {
            // limit reached
            if(stack.length >= quantity) {
                alert(quantity + " limit reached!");
                return;
            }
            src = 'http://imageshack.us/a/img20/1651/fibz.png';

            // turning green push the DOM reference to the top of the stack
            stack.push(this);
        }
        if (origsrc == 'http://imageshack.us/a/img20/1651/fibz.png') {
            src = 'http://imageshack.us/a/img703/8236/l6hu.png';
        // turning white remove the DOM reference from stack
            var self = this;
            stack = $.grep(stack, function(val) {
               return self != val;     
            })
            console.warn(stack);
        }
       $(this).attr('src', src);

    }
});
```

Comment: Your method is more efficient. Thnaks !

Answer (score 0):

use a variable to keep track of how many items have been selected, and compare it to the quantity in the select box.

```
var count = 0;
var unselected_img = 'http://imageshack.us/a/img703/8236/l6hu.png';
var selected_img = 'http://imageshack.us/a/img20/1651/fibz.png';
$('.click').on({
    'click': function () {
        var max_allowed = parseInt($("#select").val(), 10);
        var origsrc = $(this).attr('src');
        var src = '';
        if (origsrc == unselected_img && count < max_allowed) {
            src = selected_img;
            count++;
        } else if (origsrc == selected_img) {
            src = unselected_img;
            count--;
        } else {
            alert("Too many selected.");
        }

        if (src) {
            $(this).attr('src', src);
        }

    }
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4QkM8/10/)